# Receiving keyboard's willShow/willHide notifications twice on iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I found strange behaviour with keyboard's notifications on iOS 7. I have view controller with text field on it, when i push this controller into navigation controller and tap on text field - I receive `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and keyboard appears on the screen, after that, when i press a back button on navigationbar  - view controller pops, and i receive additional three notifications: `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`,  `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`. Why it's happening? why i'm receiving this two additional show and hide notifications when viewcontroller was poped and entire view is not on the screen?

video: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8255225/keyboard_notifications.mov

demo project: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8255225/test-keyboard.zip

Comment: I tried you demo project and see the double notifications. If you output the userInfo directory you'll see slightly different values. I guess it is related to the new interactive transformations on the navigation controller view stack. I would suggest creating a radar at https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Did you find any solution?